# Call Sharepoint REST api in a Office Web Addin

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, office-addins

I'm writing a Word Web Addin with Visual Studio 2017. This addin needs to call a rest api on Sharepoint Online (the search api). 
How do I authenticate on Sharepoint from the Word Web Addin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use Microsoft Graph API or SharePoint REST API. Prefered way is to use Graph if possible. For both approaches you need to use OAuth tokens, see [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)